# How to use indexOf and count on the CollectionType protocol

Tags: swift

For fun I was trying to write a protocol extension function that would let me ask an Array for the next element of the element I pass in. It would be circular such that if I passed in the last element, it would return the 0th item.  I first tried to put my method on an Array extension but I was having problems so I tried to do it on the CollectionType protocol.  I have something like:

```
extension CollectionType where Self.Generator.Element : Equatable {
final func elementAfter(element : Self.Generator.Element ) -> Self.Generator.Element? {
    let count = self.count
    if count == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    guard let index = self.indexOf(element) else {
        return nil
    }
    if index == (count - 1) {
        return self[0]
    }
    return self[index + 1]
}
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to compare the index with the count.  It says: `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Self.Index' and '(Self.Index.Distance)'`

Can somebody help explain why index and count are both not simply Int's?  How might I compare these two?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three types involved which are not identical for a generic
`CollectionType`:

- `count` returns `Self.Index.Distance`,
- `indexOf` returns a (optional) `Self.Index`,
- the constant `1` in `count - 1` and `index + 1`, which is an `Int`.

What you can do is use the `successor()` method on the index instead:

```
func elementAfter(element : Self.Generator.Element) -> Self.Generator.Element? {
    guard let index = self.indexOf(element) else {
        return nil
    }
    if index.successor() == endIndex {
        return self.first
    }
    return self[index.successor()]
}
```

Note that the check for an empty collection is not needed because
`indexOf(element)` fails in that case.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks.  What is endIndex here? A property of the CollectionType?

Comment: @darren: CollectionType inherits from the Indexable protocol, which requires startIndex and endIndex. You'll find this at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608: Protocols -> CollectionType -> Indexable.

Comment: @MartinR You are welcome ... maybe I'm becoming too much sensible to bangs ;-)